# it is happened when return struct

Tags: zig

I am a newbie to Ziglang.I try my best to describe the problem.

The following code :

```
const ArrayList = std.ArrayList;
const eql = std.mem.eql;
const test_allocator = std.testing.allocator;
const std = @import("std");
const atom_type = enum { asymbol, anumber };
const expect = @import("std").testing.expect;
const print = std.debug.print;
const CList1 = struct {
    len: usize,
    content: ArrayList(u8),
    pub fn init() CList1 {
        var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
        const allocator = gpa.allocator();
        return CList1{
            .len = 0,
            .content = ArrayList(u8).init(allocator),
        };
    }
};
test "retry" {
    var list = CList1.init();
    // var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    // const allocator = gpa.allocator();
    // var list = CList1{
    //     .len = 0,
    //     .content = ArrayList(u8).init(allocator),
    // };
    var a: u8 = 1;
    try list.content.append(a);
}
```

reports an error when executing the test

```
Segmentation fault at address 0x0
```

If I replace the code `var list = CList1.init();` with the commented off code, it works fine.
Why is this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You’re creating a new allocator in your `init` and immediately letting it go out of scope again. `init` should take an `allocator` as an argument, not create one on its own – or if for some reason you need an allocator specific to that struct instance, it should hold on to it in a field.

Comment: i got it.thank you very much:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zig std.mem.indexOf modifies \[\]const u8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77419199/zig-std-mem-indexof-modifies-const-u8)